# Java GUI searching directory files

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, search, actionlistener

These Threee Classes are what I got so far.

```
package ex;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import javax.swing.tree.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

import java.util.*;

import java.text.*;

class ATable extends AbstractTableModel {
private String title[] = { "Name", "Size", "Type", "Modified Date" };
private String val[][] = new String[1][4];

public void setValueArr(int i) {
   val = new String[i][4];
}

public int getRowCount() {
   return val.length;
}

public int getColumnCount() {
  return val[0].length;
}

public String getColumnName(int column) {
  return title[column];
}

public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
   if (columnIndex == 0)
      return true;
   else
     return false;
}

public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
  return val[row][column];
}

public void setValueAt(String aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
  val[rowIndex][columnIndex] = aValue;
}
}
```

---

```
            package ex;

            import java.awt.*;
            import java.awt.event.*;
            import javax.swing.*;
            import javax.swing.table.*;
            import javax.swing.tree.*;
            import java.io.*;
            import javax.swing.event.*;

            import java.util.*;

            import java.text.*;

            class FileViewer implements TreeWillExpandListener, TreeSelectionListener {
               private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Explorer");
               private Container con = null;

               private JSplitPane pMain = new JSplitPane();
               private JScrollPane pLeft = null;
               private JPanel pRight = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

               private DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("My Computer");
               private JTree tree;

               private JPanel pNorth = new JPanel();
               private JPanel northText = new JPanel();
               private JLabel northLabel0 = new JLabel("Path"); 
               private JTextField pathText = new JTextField();
               private JLabel northLabel1 = new JLabel("Search"); 
               private JTextField searchText = new JTextField(); 


               private Dimension dim, dim1;
               private int xpos, ypos;

               FileViewer() {
                  init();
                  start();
                  frame.setSize(800, 600);
                  dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
                  dim1 = frame.getSize();
                  xpos = (int) (dim.getWidth() / 2 - dim1.getWidth() / 2);
                  ypos = (int) (dim.getHeight() / 2 - dim1.getHeight() / 2);
                  frame.setLocation(xpos, ypos);
                  frame.setVisible(true);
               }


            void init() {
                  pMain.setResizeWeight(1);
                  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                  con = frame.getContentPane();
                  con.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

                  pathText.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 20)); 
                  searchText.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 20));
                  northText.add(northLabel0); 
                  northText.add(pathText);
                  northText.add(northLabel1); 
                  northText.add(searchText); 
                  pNorth.add(northText);
                  con.add(pNorth, "North");
                  File file = new File("C:/");
                  File list[] = file.listFiles();
                  DefaultMutableTreeNode temp;

                  for (int i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
                     temp = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(list[i].getPath());
                     temp.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("None"));
                     root.add(temp);
                  }
                  tree = new JTree(root);
                  pLeft = new JScrollPane(tree);

                  pMain.setDividerLocation(150);
                  pMain.setLeftComponent(pLeft);
                  pMain.setRightComponent(pRight);
                  con.add(pMain);
               }

               void start() {
                  tree.addTreeWillExpandListener(this);
                  tree.addTreeSelectionListener(this);
               }

               public static void main(String args[]) {
                  JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
                  new FileViewer();
               }

               String getPath(TreeExpansionEvent e) {
                  StringBuffer path = new StringBuffer();
                  TreePath temp = e.getPath();
                  Object list[] = temp.getPath();
                  for (int i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
                     if (i > 0) {
                        path.append(((DefaultMutableTreeNode) list[i]).getUserObject() + "\\");
                     }
                  }
                  return path.toString();
               }

               String getPath(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
                  StringBuffer path = new StringBuffer();
                  TreePath temp = e.getPath();
                  Object list[] = temp.getPath();
                  for (int i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
                     if (i > 0) {
                        path.append(((DefaultMutableTreeNode) list[i]).getUserObject() + "\\");
                     }
                  }
                  return path.toString();
               }

               public void getSearch(){

               }





               public void treeWillCollapse(TreeExpansionEvent event) {
               }

               public void treeWillExpand(TreeExpansionEvent e) {
                  if (((String) ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) e.getPath().getLastPathComponent()).getUserObject()).equals("My Computer")) {
                  } else {
                     try {
                        DefaultMutableTreeNode parent = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) e.getPath().getLastPathComponent();
                        File tempFile = new File(getPath(e));
                        File list[] = tempFile.listFiles();
                        DefaultMutableTreeNode tempChild;
                        for (File temp : list) {
                           if (temp.isDirectory() && !temp.isHidden()) {
                              tempChild = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(temp.getName());
                              if (true) {
                                 File inFile = new File(getPath(e) + temp.getName() + "\\");
                                 File inFileList[] = inFile.listFiles();
                                 for (File inTemp : inFileList) {
                                    if (inTemp.isDirectory() && !inTemp.isHidden()) {
                                       tempChild.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("None"));
                                       break;
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                              parent.add(tempChild);
                           }
                        }
                        parent.remove(0);
                     } catch (Exception ex) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Can't Find a File");
                     }
                  }
               }

               public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
                  if (((String) ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) e.getPath().getLastPathComponent()).getUserObject()).equals("My Computer")) {
                     pathText.setText("My Computer");
                  } else {
                     try {
                        pathText.setText(getPath(e)); 
                        pRight = new FView(getPath(e), null).getTablePanel();
                        pMain.setRightComponent(pRight);
                     } catch (Exception ex) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Can't Find a File");
                     }
                  }
               }
```

### }

```
            package ex;

            import java.awt.*;
            import java.awt.event.*;
            import javax.swing.*;
            import javax.swing.table.*;
            import javax.swing.tree.*;
            import java.io.*;
            import javax.swing.event.*;

            import java.util.*;

            import java.text.*;

            class FView {
               private ATable at = new ATable();
               private JTable jt = new JTable(at);

               private JPanel pMain = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
               private JScrollPane pCenter = new JScrollPane(jt);

               private File file;
               private File list[];
               private long size = 0, time = 0;

               FView(String str, String searchKey) {
                  init();
                  if (searchKey!=null){
                      search(str, searchKey);
                  }
                  start(str);

               }

               void init() {
                  pMain.add(pCenter, "Center");
               }

               void start(String strPath) {
                  file = new File(strPath);
                  list = file.listFiles();
                  at.setValueArr(list.length);
                  for (int i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
                     size = list[i].length();
                     time = list[i].lastModified();
                     for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                        switch (j) {
                        case 0:
                           at.setValueAt(list[i].getName(), i, j);
                           break;
                        case 1:
                           if (list[i].isFile())
                              at.setValueAt(Long.toString((long) Math.round(size / 1024.0)) + "Kb", i, j);
                           break;
                        case 2:
                           if (list[i].isFile()) {
                              at.setValueAt(getLastName(list[i].getName()), i, j);
                           } else
                              at.setValueAt("파일폴더", i, j);
                           break;
                        case 3:
                           at.setValueAt(getFormatString(time), i, j);
                           break;
                        }
                     }
                  }
                  jt.repaint();
                  pCenter.setVisible(false);
                  pCenter.setVisible(true);
               }

               void search(String strPath, String searchKey){
                   file = new File(strPath);
                      list = file.listFiles();
                      at.setValueArr(list.length);
                      for (int i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
                         size = list[i].length();
                         time = list[i].lastModified();
                         for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                            switch (j) {
                            case 0:
                               at.setValueAt("zzzzzzzzz", i, j);
                               break;
                            case 1:
                               if (list[i].isFile())
                                  at.setValueAt(Long.toString((long) Math.round(size / 1024.0)) + "Kb", i, j);
                               break;
                            case 2:
                               if (list[i].isFile()) {
                                  at.setValueAt(getLastName(list[i].getName()), i, j);
                               } else
                                  at.setValueAt("File Folder", i, j);
                               break;
                            case 3:
                               at.setValueAt(getFormatString(time), i, j);
                               break;
                            }
                         }
                      }
                      jt.repaint();
                      pCenter.setVisible(false);
                      pCenter.setVisible(true);
                   }

               String getLastName(String name) {
                  int pos = name.lastIndexOf(".");
                  String result = name.substring(pos + 1, name.length());
                  return result;
               }

               String getFormatString(long time) {
                  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a");
                  Date d = new Date(time);
                  String temp = sdf.format(d);
                  return temp;
               }

               JPanel getTablePanel() {
                  return pMain;
               }
            }
```

What I want is 'searching a file' function on the right side of path textfield.

The location of search textfield is fine now, but i have no clue how to add function on it.

It should show a file that contains a word which the user type on search text field. (The file that is in current directory ONLY. Don't need to show a file in subdirectory)

And when the search textfield is blank, it should show all the files in current directory as usual.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

```
con.add(pNorth, "North");
```

Don't use magic strings. The API will have variables you can use:

```
con.add(pNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

> It should show a file that contains a word which the user type on search text field

You need to add a `DocumentListener` to the `Document` of the `JTextField`. An event will be fired whenever text is added or removed and you can then do your search.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for more information and examples.